# how do i get a domain to trigger i18n in django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, dns

So over the last few weeks I have been preparing a few different languages for our platform and was wondering how you go about getting a domain name to activate a certain language?

For instance, if I have site with 5 languages.

Swedish,
English,
Norwegian,
Danish
and Finnish

and one of my users visit the www.domainname.se I want it to trigger the swedish part.

Any tips?

Comment: Be easier if we knew which web server.

Comment: @Ignacio, just added it to the headline, using django/python

Comment: "Django" is not a web server. No, it isn't. Don't argue.

Comment: Check out [transurlvania](https://github.com/trapeze/transurlvania)

Comment: @ignacio, hehe sorry Centos 5.4

Comment: That's still not a web server.

Comment: @ApPeL: Hint.  It's one of these: Apache httpd.  IIS.  ngingx.  Lighttpd.

Comment: centos with apache httpd

Answer (score 0):

With httpd, just use [`RequestHeader`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) to frob the `Accept-Language` header for the virtual host, since Django [looks at it to discover language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference).

```
RequestHeader append Accept-Language sv-se
```